# Did the Prophet suggest to a poor man to marry twice, who then became very rich?

Tags: hadith, nikah, source-identification

Recently, I heard from someone that a person came to the Prophet and told him that he was very poor. The Prophet suggested that he get married. He went and got married and became poorer. He came back to the Prophet and explained the situation to him. The Prophet again told him to go and get another wife. He did and became very rich.

I am looking for the Hadith in which this story was reported.  I can't seem to locate it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Assalamu alaikum,

May Allah bless you and I with beneficial knowledge, ameen

I have heard this 'story'...

This story goes something like this:

A man came to the Prophet (Peace & Blessings of Allah upon him) and complained about being poor, so the Prophet told him to get married. Then the man came back again with the same complaint, so the Prophet again told him to get married. The man came back a third time, and still the Prophet told him to get married. After the fourth time, the man got married to a woman who knew how to sew (she was a tailor), so she used to make clothes and sell them and she also taught all the other 3 wives how to sew, so the man became rich.

**This is a fabrication. No such hadeeth exists**

And Allah alone knows best

Wassalaamu alaik.

Answer (score 0):

The hadith is not a fabrication, but an authentic one. This is how the hadith goes. The man was married to a wife and after sometime, he went to the prophet, pbuh and complained that he is married, but poor, and the prophet advised him to marry another wife, he did, but still came to the prophet with the same complain and he got the same advice up to the time he married the 4th wife. Now, the point here is the poor state of the man. This man was not poor financially, on the contrary, he was a very wealthy man. The word used in Arabic for poor refers to lack of issue, that is child or children, which to them, no matter how rich you are, if you don't have a child or children, you are a poor man. So, when he married the 4th wife, that one got pregnant and the moment she delivered, the others started bearing children too. The 4th wife like now opened the door to the riches, that is fruits of the womb. May God bless us for the good we do and forgive us for our mistakes and limited knowledge.